# calling 2 or more methods from from the same batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have 2 methods in my batch script and I have to call them and execute them within the same script itself.

```
:methodname
some for loops
GOTO:EOF
call: methodname


:methodname2
some for loops
GOTO:EOF
call: methodname2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The positions of your `call` statements are wrong.

Batch doesn't know anything about `functions` it only knows labels.
The code will be executed line by line and a label is simply a line, starting with a colon, and it will do nothing, but can be called.

To solve your problem you can move your calls.

```
call :methodname
call :methodname2
goto :eof

:methodname
some for loops
GOTO :EOF

:methodname2
some for loops
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Dude, you are a life saver. thanks a lot. it perfectly works.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also make two batch files, one main where you have:

```
call methodname2.bat
call :methodname
goto :eof

:methodname
some for loops
GOTO :EOF
```

methodname2.bat holds:

```
:methodname2
some for loops
exit
```

Comment: Thank you, MrBigBoy but i already got the answer thanks anyway.